# What's the best way to achieve a popup in Cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iOS game using Cocos2D. I would like to show a popup, something like UIAlertView, but completely custom. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!
Benza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use a layer for this and to pause the scene. Here are a couple forum posts from the Cocos2d site that go over this a bit:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6511

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1954

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exactly what I tried to do. 
(I wrote this possible solution in the question, but I don't know why Sold Out Activist removed that part, too much liberty of edit question by others!)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately pausing the scene means you will also pause whatever you have in your popup.
Maybe it's not your case, but I quite often have scrolling lists in my popups. If I pause the scene it will not work.
I've added a method to CCNode which goes through all children and stops their activity rather than pausing the scene.
If you open the popup as a child of your scene then first you deactivate all children of the scene and then open the popup. This means that you can still do whatever you want in your popup and everything else is paused or does not respond to touch [like menus].